# Issues creating client for WCF Service using Federation

Tags: wcf, federation

After modifying my service to use federation (see web.config below) I'm having trouble on my client getting it connected. In all that I have read it seems I should be able to just create

```
var client = new MyService()
```

and then set username and password on that credential and then WCF takes care of the STS token stuff, but I do not have a constructor that takes 0 arguments, I only have one that takes a binding and endpoint address. I do not see a way to create the binding manually and would just like to use it the default way, before when I was just using a basicHTTPBinding with Https I was able to create the client with the default constructor I don't see why this does not follow same logic.

The service has web.config as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="[DecrpytKey]" validation="SHA1" validationKey="[ValidationKey]" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsFederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsFedBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://myservice.cloudapp.net/MyService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsFederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsFedBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message>
              <issuer address="http://mysts.com"/>
              <issuerMetadata address="https://mysts.com/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
              <claimTypeRequirements>
                <add claimType="http://mysts.com/user/UserDomain" isOptional="true"/>
                <add claimType="http://mysts.com/user/Alias" isOptional="true"/>
              </claimTypeRequirements>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsFederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
            <!--Certificate added by Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio.-->
            <serviceCertificate findValue="[Thumbprint]" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" suppressAuditFailure="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
   [Some connection strings]
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://myservice.cloudapp.net/MyService.svc" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="http://mysts.com">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="[Thumbprint]" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://mysts.com" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://mysts.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="productionSTS" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```